# Wordpress theme css customization: how to remove padding on sides of page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes

I'm trying to customize the theme I'm using (biancaa) by changing the CSS of a child theme. I've been at it for a few hours (tinkering using inspect element) and have had no avail. Any advice would be greatly apprecciated.

1. I would like to completely remove the left and right padding so that the black line on the bottom of the menu extends to the edges of the screen, and the post fills up 95% the entire page width
2. I would like to get the menu to stick to the top when you scroll down

The site:
http://www.anniekip.com/

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I edited your post to embed your screenshot. You can embed images by pressing the image toolbar icon or using markdown syntax manually.

Answer (score 0):

try this

Open the following files

http://www.anniekip.com/wp-content/themes/biancaa/style.min.css

http://www.anniekip.com/wp-content/themes/biancaa/style.css

And look at the whole file with the following class

```
 .site
```

Set the padding always well

```
 padding: 0;
```

Comment: Not only does this not work, but you should never edit a min file.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this purely in the css.  You will have to edit the html for each theme template to remove the nav out of the wrapping container, and then edit some of the css to display the nav correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Add css on style.css file

```
.container {
    max-width : 100% !important ;
}

.site {
    max-width : 100% !important ;
    padding :0 !important
}
```